# Show error when a function is called inside / outside of certain folders

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to, for example, make PhpStorm show an error (on the function call and for the file) when function `xyx()` is called in any file in any folder other than in folder `abc`?

Specific use case if it helps:

I want to show an error where ever I use the `env()` function outside of the `config` folder in a Laravel app - because, after running `php artisan config:cache`, which one does when deploying a Laravel app, all calls to `env()` return null, and I'm worried it's easy to accidentally use `env()` in my codebase rather than `config()`

Comment: For reference purposes: the same on PhpStorm Forums -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8099535179154-Show-error-when-a-function-is-called-inside-outside-of-certain-folders

Comment: As for the actual issue -- [Structural search and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html) should be able to help here. 1) Make a search pattern first 2) Save as template/inspection 3) Make a [custom scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#creating-a-new-custom-scope) that will include locations where you want this to be reported.

Comment: 4) Then go to the Inspections and find that particular SSR there (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Structural search` node) -- each inspection [can be configured per scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/inspections-settings.html#5). So just add your newly created scope and have it enabled while disable it for "Everywhere else"

Comment: Excellent -- please post your solution as an answer: add the template text you have used + a few screenshots (links if necessary) etc -- something that will be enough for less knowledgeable person to see what this is about/how it actually works. It will help other users with similar needs. You can accept the answer/mark as resolved later (in a few hours or a day or two). Question with accepted answer is more visible in the results and easier to find. Cheers!